# Generic delete and update using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Consider the situation: 
I want delete and update items from Database using Entity Framework. I want to achieve it generically using LINQ to entities provided the Database context, ID of row to be deleted, column to be updated and the value to which it should be updated are already available with us.

How can i do it generically. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A remark, you should delete when operation = delete. Now it is Add !

Comment: @hazjack According the the requirement I need to do opposite of it :)

Comment: Please share us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can use **DAO** object like Repository between DB and your code, some like this

```
public class Dao<T> : where T:class {
    internal virtual DbSet<T> EntitySet {
        get {
            return DB.Set<T>();
        }
    }

    public void DeleteById(int id) {
        T instance = FindById(id);
        Delete(instance);
    }


    public void Update(T instance) {
        DB.Entry(instance).State = EntityState.Modified;
        DB.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And use code

```
Dao<someClass> daoClass = new Dao<someClass>(new dbContext());
daoClass.DeleteById(5);
daoClass.Update(someClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Day, I'm not sure about the question but I'll give an idea on how to do update and delete

Update

```
 using (var db = new DbContext())
 {
    var tobeupdatedrow = db.TableNames.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id== Id);
    if (tobeupdatedrow != null)
    {
        tobeupdatedrow.tobeupdatedcolumn = "Some new value";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

Delete

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
 {
    var tobedeletedrow = db.TableNames.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id== Id);
    if (tobedeletedrow != null)
    {
        db.TableNames.Remove(tobedeletedrow);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```